# Need help changing prices on multiple HTML pages, using regular expressions dreamweaver, want to multiply the price by 4

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

My task is simple. I want to replace all the prices (on HTML pages) marked by their value multiplied by 4.

So $500 should become $2000. What would the code be for that?

Then I would like bigger prices, like $5000, to only be multiplied by 2
What would be the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done by a simple regex-replacement. Realize that a regex pattern does not match numbers (which can be operated on with +, -, etc.), but it matches strings.

The only possibility would be to replace `\$5000` with `\$10000` (the `$` is a special char and needs to be escaped). I realize that with many different amounts, this is not a viable solution for you. However, if you have just a handful of different amount, you could do a couple of such replacements (be careful not to replace amounts twice!).

Comment: thx for the replies, do you have any other software easier to use,

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that knows about the structure of HTML.